# get real line by line from textView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

is it possible to get real line by line value from textView? Even if it's sizable, i want to get every line in forEach.My textView is pinch zooming which means there's more and less lines when we zoom text. I tried like that but in every change lines are still the same, like in the beginning

```
 val vto = textView.viewTreeObserver
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        
        val lines = mutableListOf<CharSequence>()
        val lineCount: Int = textView.lineCount
        for (line in 0 until lineCount) {

            val start = textView.layout.getLineStart(line)
            val end = textView.layout.getLineEnd(line)
            val substring = textView.text.subSequence(start, end)
            lines.add(substring)
            Log.d("lines",lines.toString())
        }

    }
```

Number of lines is changing, but lines are still the same.

Comment: Text lines are strings ending with a newline character `\n`. The TextView might wrap long lines to make all text visible but it does not interfere with line ends.

Comment: so is it possible to find "end of line" but just wrapped?

Comment: I dont know. But you could change the subject and text of your post as you dont want the real text line but the wrapped ones. Soft carriage return.

Comment: `Number of lines is changing,` Are you telling that `textView.lineCount` changes while resizing?

Comment: Yes, while I am resizing lineCount is changing to real number of lines on screen